# using StreamWriter on server in C#

Tags: c#, .net, streamwriter

I try to write to a remote machine with the following code:

```
StreamWriter(@"\\" + remoteMachine + "\\admin$\\" + fileName);
```

i get the following error **Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.** 
i got the user name, domain and password. how can i write with credentials? 

if i already been to that computer in this session there is no problem, but if it's a new session the computer doesn't recognize the location

how can i write with credentials?

Comment: What identity do you want to pass to the remote server? The application identity, the identity of the user using the application, or something else?

Comment: the identity that can use the remote server

Comment: Try to remove the @ `(i.e StreamWriter("\\" + remoteMachine...) )`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to impersonate the identity before using the `StreamWriter`. [WindowsIdentity.Impersonate Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w070t6ka.aspx) article has a great example of doing so.

Inside this code you would use the `StreamWriter`:

```
using (WindowsImpersonationContext impersonatedUser = newId.Impersonate()) {
    StreamWriter(@"\\" + remoteMachine + "\\admin$\\" + fileName);
}
```

Comment: what is `newId`?

Comment: @Si8 It's an instance of `WindowsIdentity`.