# Write file to windows share using Streamreader

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to write a file to another machine (not on the same domain), using a share that is available on that machine. I saw this question, [using StreamWriter on server in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6829432/using-streamwriter-on-server-in-c-sharp) , and I guess the person who asked the question got the answer, but I'm not use exactly how to do this. THe MSDN article it points to requires you to make a whole class to support an impersonation - is there no easier way to do this? Can I make a user on my machine that can do something like that? Can I set up my asp.net user to impersonate, or run IIS using a different user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a mapped drive to the network share on your web server or you can setup impersonation in `web.config`. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xh507fc5%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

But I suggest you follow the code to [impersonate a specific user](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306158#4) because it's a better practice.

Since the resource is not on the same domain as your web server, you'll need to setup trust between the domains. Here's a [start](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc787646%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [impersonation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa292118%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). Add next code to your web.config

```
<system.web>
    <identity impersonate="true" userName="MyUser" password="MyPassword"/>
</system.web>
```